# tried to jump infinity qx56 now none of dashlights work

Tags: electrical, battery, infiniti, instrument-cluster, qx56

a couple days ago I had to use my jumpbox to start  my infinity qx56 4wd, then it kept getting worse where I had to jump it everytime I turned it off , and my jumpbox wasn't enouph so I hooked up my starter accidentally put it on 240 quickstart and when I plugged it in in shot sparks and my battery was smoking. I checked the cables and they were on the right way .

so I bought a new battery and the truck fires right up now but I have no instrument cluster , no screen display ,no radio or any accessories , except the lighter plugs . headlights ,wipers, tail lights ,power windows and seats and locks  all work. Even though the ac/heater isn't turned on the heater is blowing full blast , I had to pull the fuse to turn it off . also my tow mode light is on and though I click the button it won't turn off . I've checked fuses and didn't see any breaks . like I said the truck fires right up and runs fine my dash is just dark .

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: You know you have two fuse blocks, right? One in the passenger compartment, one under the hood? Check both.

Comment: yea it actually has 3 fuse panels I checked them all I didn't think I seen any breaks but some of the smaller ones are hard to see .  I'll check again , thanks for the comment

Comment: thank you MTA  I went over the fuses again and found I think  3 blown ones I missed .I replaced those and got the radio and the display screen to start working

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of giving this question an answer that can be found in a search, I'm providing this answer to summarize the resolution of your problem that was solved in comments. (Comments don't show up in searches.)

Your question said, "I've checked fuses and didn't see any breaks" so I commented that your car has two fuse blocks, one in the passenger compartment and one under the hood, and you should check both.

You replied that the car actually has three fuse blocks, and in checking more carefully, you found three blown fuses, you replaced them and now the radio and display screen are working. No word on the instrument cluster but I'm hoping that it's working too.

If all systems are now working, that's the end of it. If the instrument cluster is still not working, a re-check of all possible fuses that might affect it would be in order. Also note that some instrument clusters have an additional fuse mounted directly on the circuit board, which can only be accessed and replaced by removing the instrument cluster. I don't know if your car is one of those.

Comment: thank you again for your comment ...and no the instrument cluster is still not working plus the heater blower Is blowing full blast I can't get it to stop because the hvac also isn't working so had to pull the fuse  to turn the blower off ...coincidentally (?) my shifter won't go in gear now unless I take a small screwdriver and push the button in beside the shifter...I've went over all the fuses again and seen nothing ...maybe I'll have to pull the instrument cluster ...dammit